# Mysql password expired and my mysql.user table is corrupted

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Okay, I have a little problem.

My password is expired and my users table is corrupted. I can login via

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but on every action I perform I get the folowing error:

> Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted.

I have read that you can fix the mysql.user table with the folowing command:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

But when I do that I get the folowing error:

> mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1862: Your password has expired. To log in you 
>   must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. while 
>   connecting to the MySQL server
>   Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
>   So, How do I fix this?

I have backups of all my tables so I won't be a problem if I have to reset all my databases.

(why the weird format? Stackoverflow thinks it's all code and wants me to put it in code blocks, otherwise I can not save it)

EDIT:

I know my password. That's not the problem at all.

My problem is that the password is expired and I am not able to do anything becuase my mysql.user is corrupted!

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable the password expiration option: edit the my.cnf and put

```
[mysqld]
default_password_lifetime=0
```

and try to restart mysql server and try again login again.
the source is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html

For repairing the database you run `mysqlcheck --repair --databases db_name` or `mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases` for repairing all databases
The source is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html
You could first try to repair the database then you could try to disable password lifetime.

Comment: Well, that's not really working. I have to enter a password when doing `mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases` When I enter the password it says it's expired. I have also tried to disable the password expiration but without any luck.

Comment: Okay, did you restart mysql service? if yes then try this other approach save this statement to a file MySQL 5.7.6 and later: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';` or `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');` for MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier then run `mysqld --init-file=/path/to/file &` source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Well, yes, I tried that. I only keep getting this error: ` Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted` With everything I try

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.
Just reinstalled mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when restoring an old backup from 2018, reinstalling MySQL as you said in a comment didn't solve the issue.

How I did:

1. Stop MySQL service
2. Run `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

   (if you get an error you may need to manually create and chown the directory /run/mysqld)

   --skip-grant-tables will allow passwordless logins and will also disable any check on the password expiration
3. Now run `mysql_upgrade --force` and `mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases`
4. You can now kill the running mysqld_safe (`ps aux | grep mysql` to find the PID to kill) and then start the server normally with `service mysql start`.

   In my case it didn't work and I still had the "Expected 45, found 46" error. In that case go ahead:
5. Stop the server again and restart it in safe mode as point 2 above
6. Now you should be able to **dump the content**, but we must exclude the `mysql` schema from being dumped.

   Since mysqldump doesn't have a --exclude-database option, we need to get the list of databases to dump. To get the list of existing databases, except system schemas, run:

   `mysql -Nse "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME SEPARATOR ' ') FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema','sys');"`
7. Remove from the list any other db you don't need, and run the dump:

   `mysqldump --databases db1 db2 ... db50 > mysqldump.sql`
8. Kill mysqld, move the datadir away and create an empty one (`mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old && mkdir /var/lib/mysql && chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`)
9. `service mysql start` and a fresh datadir will be populated.
10. Run `mysql_secure_installation` to set a new root password
11. Import the dump file:
    `cat mysqldump.sql | mysql -u root -p`

After that, the server is UP and running without issues.